# Leaflet marker popup link from outside of map dynamically

Tags: leaflet, javascript, json, maps

I am using Leaflet JavaScript library to show some earthquake informations. You can able to see few red circles on map. When you click that red circle it will display few details in popup.

I want to show the popup when you click the link from outside of map. This ([answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17632359/how-to-open-leaflet-marker-popup-from-link-outside-of-map/18859798#18859798)) is useful. But, I want to achieve it without ID? I mean if I have more than 30 markers on map and also I don't have any ID, just class names in my links. How do I trigger popup when I click a link from outside of map?

**[JsBin](https://jsbin.com/vekavomovi/edit?html,output)**

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Leaflet</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7/leaflet.css" />



  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="map" style="width: 400px; height: 400px;"></div>
    <script src="https://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script>

  var object = {"type":"FeatureCollection","metadata":{"generated":1564051101000,"url":"https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?format=geojson&starttime=2019-07-20&endtime=2019-07-21&minmagnitude=5","title":"USGS Earthquakes","status":200,"api":"1.8.1","count":4},"features":[{"type":"Feature","properties":{"mag":5.2000000000000002,"place":"79km ENE of L'Esperance Rock, New Zealand","time":1563662132538,"updated":1563663302040,"tz":-720,"url":"https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/us70004pu1","detail":"https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?eventid=us70004pu1&format=geojson","felt":null,"cdi":null,"mmi":null,"alert":null,"status":"reviewed","tsunami":0,"sig":416,"net":"us","code":"70004pu1","ids":",us70004pu1,","sources":",us,","types":",geoserve,origin,phase-data,","nst":null,"dmin":1.9299999999999999,"rms":1.28,"gap":70,"magType":"mww","type":"earthquake","title":"M 5.2 - 79km ENE of L'Esperance Rock, New Zealand"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-178.1173,-31.174800000000001,35]},"id":"us70004pu1"},
{"type":"Feature","properties":{"mag":5.5999999999999996,"place":"23km NNW of Kandrian, Papua New Guinea","time":1563655424914,"updated":1563741959328,"tz":600,"url":"https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/us70004psn","detail":"https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?eventid=us70004psn&format=geojson","felt":1,"cdi":4.2999999999999998,"mmi":4.4779999999999998,"alert":"green","status":"reviewed","tsunami":1,"sig":483,"net":"us","code":"70004psn","ids":",us70004psn,","sources":",us,","types":",dyfi,geoserve,losspager,moment-tensor,origin,phase-data,shakemap,","nst":null,"dmin":3.2029999999999998,"rms":0.89000000000000001,"gap":28,"magType":"mww","type":"earthquake","title":"M 5.6 - 23km NNW of Kandrian, Papua New Guinea"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[149.5069,-6.0086000000000004,59.789999999999999]},"id":"us70004psn"},
{"type":"Feature","properties":{"mag":5.0999999999999996,"place":"Easter Island region","time":1563647034336,"updated":1563892918040,"tz":-420,"url":"https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/us70004pra","detail":"https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?eventid=us70004pra&format=geojson","felt":null,"cdi":null,"mmi":null,"alert":null,"status":"reviewed","tsunami":0,"sig":400,"net":"us","code":"70004pra","ids":",us70004pra,","sources":",us,","types":",geoserve,origin,phase-data,","nst":null,"dmin":2.7559999999999998,"rms":0.71999999999999997,"gap":118,"magType":"mb","type":"earthquake","title":"M 5.1 - Easter Island region"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-111.38379999999999,-29.3232,10]},"id":"us70004pra"},
{"type":"Feature","properties":{"mag":5.0999999999999996,"place":"136km ESE of Pangai, Tonga","time":1563635789233,"updated":1563636880040,"tz":-720,"url":"https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/us70004pp5","detail":"https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?eventid=us70004pp5&format=geojson","felt":null,"cdi":null,"mmi":null,"alert":null,"status":"reviewed","tsunami":0,"sig":400,"net":"us","code":"70004pp5","ids":",us70004pp5,","sources":",us,","types":",geoserve,origin,phase-data,","nst":null,"dmin":3.2749999999999999,"rms":1.3100000000000001,"gap":116,"magType":"mww","type":"earthquake","title":"M 5.1 - 136km ESE of Pangai, Tonga"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-173.15700000000001,-20.294899999999998,10]},"id":"us70004pp5"}],"bbox":[-178.1173,-31.1748,10,149.5069,-6.0086,59.79]}


   var i = 0;

   document.writeln("<div>");
   for(i = 0;i<object.features.length;i++) {

    var timestamp = object.features[i].properties.time / 1000;
    date = new Date(timestamp * 1000);
    dateString = date.toUTCString();

    var today = date;
    today.setHours(today.getHours() + 4);


    // maps

    document.writeln("<div class='list'>");
    document.writeln("<div>" + object.features[i].properties.mag + " Mag</div>");
    document.writeln("</div>");
  }
  document.writeln("</div>");


        var map = L.map('map').setView([-31.174800000000001,-178.1173], 2);


        // load a tile layer
        L.tileLayer(
            'https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}', {
            attribution: 'Tiles &copy; Esri &mdash; Source: Esri, DeLorme, NAVTEQ, USGS, Intermap, iPC, NRCAN, Esri Japan, METI, Esri China (Hong Kong), Esri (Thailand), TomTom, 2012',
            maxZoom: 18,
            }).addTo(map);


        // load GeoJSON from an external file
        $.getJSON("https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?format=geojson&starttime=2019-07-20&endtime=2019-07-21&minmagnitude=5",function(data){

          var geojsonMarkerOptions = {
            opacity: 0.8,
            fillOpacity: 0.6
          };

          // color indication by magnitude
          geoLayer = L.geoJson(data, {

          // popup div content
          onEachFeature: function(feature,layer) {

          // variable1 = L.marker([-31.174800000000001,-178.1173]).bindPopup('The html content').addTo(map);

          var popupText = "<b>Magnitude:</b> " + feature.properties.mag
                      + "<br><b>Location:</b> " + feature.properties.place;


                      layer.bindPopup(popupText, {
                        closeButton: true,
                        offset: L.point(0, -20)
                      });
                      layer.on('click', function() {
                        layer.openPopup();
                      });     
          },


          style: function(feature) {
            var mag = feature.properties.mag;
            if (mag >= 4.0) {
              return { color: "red" }; 
            } 
            else if (mag >= 3.0) {
              return { color: "orange" };
            } 
            else if (mag >= 2.0) {
              return { color: "yellow" };
            } 
            else {
              return { color: "black" };
            }
          },


          // add GeoJSON layer to the map once the file is loaded
          pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
              return L.circleMarker(latlng, geojsonMarkerOptions);
            },
          }).addTo(map);

        });


</script>


  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Cross-posted from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57286300/show-leaflet-marker-popup-from-outside-of-map-dynamically

Comment: @IvanSanchez I have tried and got the output result and also I have posted an answer (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57286300/show-leaflet-marker-popup-from-outside-of-map-dynamically/57289658#57289658) in that question. Shall I delete this question here?

Answer (score 1):

Here is something similar : http://www.gistechsolutions.com/leaflet/DEMO/baseball/BaseballPanelSelect2.html The popups work as expected. If you select a distance (top right) and then click on the map, all points in that distance get selected and show up in the sidebar table. From here you can select on and it will zoom to that point. This was my way of not making the sidebar having too many records.

The key is using a unique attribute as the leaflet id, like:

```
        onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
            layer._leaflet_id = feature.properties.Team;
```

Then for the table, I create a td that has the team name in it. (matches the leaflet_id)

Finally when they click in the table I get the td cell that has the team name which is the leaflet_id and fire off a click event.

```
 $('#myTable tr').click(function(x) {
        theTeam = (this.getElementsByTagName("td").item(0)).innerHTML;
        map._layers[theTeam].fire('click');
        var coords = map._layers[theTeam]._latlng;
        map.setView(coords, 12);
     });
```

Right click on my page an view source, it may help. You do need that unique value to make the leaflet DI with. If you don't need the distance select, just create the table when it loads. I'd just make an array, an in the forEachFeature push the unique name into it, then use this array to create the table.